# Как работает bool?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c++

Например такая запись:

```
bool asd = 1 < 2 && true;
```

Либо такая (в операторе if):

```
bool key=false;
if(key&&myFunc())//myFunc - громадная функция возвращающая bool
{
...
}
```

в случае с if, как определяется итоговый результат(true/false)?

- сначала проверяется key на true и,
     если результат отрицательный, то
     сразу прекращает работу с результатом false, не
     добравшись до myFunc()
- проверяется и
     то, и то, а потом смотрит на
     результаты и выносит итоговый
- как-то иначе

Вопрос возник из-за желания ускорить процесс выполнения программы, в моем случае уменьшить нагрузку на сервер всякими проверками. например на ту же самую валидность полей. К тому же, ведь могут направить ддос программу на отправку post запросов на сервер, который с каждым разом проверяет эти данные.

У меня такой же случай как во втором примере. Можно конечно написать:

```
if(key)
{
  if(myFunc())
  {
     ...
  }
}
```

Но это совсем не симпатично выглядит, особенно когда подобное в коде встречается довольно часто.

Возвращаюсь к вопросу:
как `bool` становится `true` или `false`, когда используется оператор AND(&&).

Comment: большое спасибо всем за такие подробные ответы. Но меня интересовал лишь вопрос как, поэтапно, bool переменная получает результат с использованием оператора AND(&&). И ответ был получен через 3 минуты, п.с. отличный сайт.

Comment: Я просто балдею от таких вопросов. Написать пять строк и проверить IMHO на порядок быстрее, чем прочитать ответы (пусть даже оперативно поступившие).

Comment: я так и сделал, но не был уверен на 100% и решил еще спросить на всякий случай.

Comment: У вас в метках стоит "c++".

Потому говорю: в Стандарте ничего не сказнао про то, в каком порядке будут вычисляться логические выражения. Т.е. знайте, что они будут вычисляться почти оптимально(оптимизаторы на что?), но полностью рассчитывать на это не стоит!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В выражении `a && b` сначала вычисляется операнд `a`, затем (если `a` не `false`) - `b`. В вашем случае, если `key` - `false`, то вызова `myFunc()` не будет.

Answer (score 4):

**В этом случае:**

```
bool asd = 1 < 2 && true;
```

Происходит то же самое, что и при:

```
bool asd = 1 < 2;
```

Так как вторая часть постоянна, т.е существенной логики не несет.
**Это же:**

```
if(key && myFunc())
```

Возвратит true лишь тогда, когда `key==true и результат выполнения myFunc()==true`. Судя по вашему примеру, этого никогда не произойдет, т.к изначально `key=false`. **=>**

```
if(key) - сокращение от if(key==true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Позвольте рекомендовать Вам не использовать записей подобных коду №1, поскольку он крайне непрозрачный и, кроме того, справа стоит константа; так что уж лучше сразу написать что true.

Код №2 никогда не будет выполнен, так как в скобках у if() стоит false. "сначала проверяется key на true и, если результат отрицательный, то сразу прекращает работу с результатом false, не добравшись до myFunc()" - именно так и будет.

Comment: я знаю, это я все к примеру написал, чтобы было понятнее

Answer (score 1):

В C# рекомендуется явно задавать условие на истинность! Дело в том что если функция вернёт 0(int), а Вы проверите вот так `if(myFunc()) {...}`, то это не сработает! Более того VS сообщит об ошибке. В операторах условий и итераций должен быть тип boolean. То есть `if(myFunc()) {...}` Неправильно! Нужно `if(myFunc() > 0) {...}`

```
if(bool) {...} Числа != boolean.
```

Comment: Наверное все таки если по аналогии с С и С++, то

    if (myFunc() != 0) { // true 
       и
    if (myFunc() == 0) { // false

сравнение строго на больше как-то глаз режет.

Comment: Я просто привёл пример, там уже как удобнее )

Answer (score 0):

```
bool asd = 1 < 2 && true;
```

&&=логическое "и", сначала выполняется сравнение 1<2  оно возвращает значение (false=0 или true=1+) затем возвращённое значение сравнивается с true и если оба значения "правда" в переменную asd записывается true (тобишь 1+)

1. Все булевы-переменные по сути int-переменные с двумя значениями ложь (то есть 0) или правда (любое значение неравное нулю)
2. `if(key && myFunc())` если обе функции или переменные хранят\возвращают значения !=0 (не ноль) то if будет истинно и выполнится,  если хотя-бы одно будет 0 то if невыполнится
3. Стандартные операторы условий в с++ (в других языках они тоже есть но по другому пишутся)

== -равно? 1==1=1; всё остальное будет 0=false

!= -не равно? 1!=1=0; всё остальное будет истинное 1=true;

&& -логическое "и" 1&&1=1;  0&&1=0;  1&&0=0; 0&&0=0;

|| -логическое "или"  1||1=1;  0||1=1;  1||0=1;  0||0=0;

ну >,<,>=,<= аналогичны обычной алгебре

в математике есть направление "математическая логика" или "булева алгебра"

----------добавлено спустя пару часов----------

**eigenein** писал

> В выражении a && b сначала вычисляется операнд a, затем (если a не false) - b. В вашем случае, если key - false, то вызова myFunc() не будет.

это верно только при условии что **ни**где в программе переменная key  не изменяется (тогда компилятор её помечает как константу и соответственно не запускает myFunc())

при этом она не должна изменяться ни до ни после **if(key&&myFunc())** если же она изменяется то myFunc() будет запускаться в любом случае

Comment: В C# типы `int` и `bool` не эквивалентны.

Comment: один из тегов в его вопросе "С++"да и лечится это очень просто (сравниваем с нулём)вместо  if(k1 && (x>y))пишем   if((k1>0) && (x>y))за шарп пока не брался, потому если ответишь, зачем это было сделано буду очень признателен...

Comment: Это сделано для безопасности!

Comment: > это верно только при условии что нигде в программе переменная key не изменяется (тогда компилятор её помечает как константу и соответственно не запускает myFunc())
> при этом она не должна изменяться ни до ни после if(key&&myFunc()) если же она изменяется то myFunc() будет запускаться в любом случае

В .NET это неправда. `myFunc()` вычисляется только если значение первого операнда на момент проверки условия равно `true`. Всегда.

Comment: В `C++,` разумеется, аналогично, и это формально называется [`Short-circuit evaluation.`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Comment: в С++(99) как раз не аналогично там если переменная не const то   myFunc() запустится, проверял в VS 2010 в режиме консоли.

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat Нет такого стандарта C++99. И вы точно где-то ошиблись в своих экспериментах.

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat, как Вы считаете, код

    #include <stdio.h>
    
    char * mystrdup(char *s) 
    {
      printf ("mystrdup <%s>\n",s);
      return strdup(s);
    }

    int main(int ac,char *av[])
    { 
      char *p = av[1], *q;
    
      if (p && (q = mystrdup(p)))
        printf ("strdup(%s) = [%s]\n",p,q);
      else
        printf ("xaxa\n");

      return 0;
    }


что будет печатать?